Conformal map of two intersecting circles
While studying for my Complex Analysis course, I came across the following exercise:

You are given the following region
$$\Omega = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z - i| < \sqrt{2} \text{ or } |z + i| < \sqrt{2} \right\}$$
Give a Möbius transformation that maps $\Omega$ onto a sector $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |\arg z| < \theta \}$ for some $\theta > 0$. What is $\theta$?

To construct a Möbius transformation, I normally pick 3 points and assign a new value to them, for example 1 goes to $\infty$ and so on.
In this example however, I can only see 2 points to work with, namely -1 and 1, where the two circles intersect. I do not find a handy 3rd point I can use.
I was thinking about projecting -1 to 0 and 1 to $\infty$. This gives the following possible Möbius transformation:
$$
f(z) = \frac{az + a}{cz -c}
$$
However, I have no idea how to check if this mapping is correct.
PS: the question after this is to give a series of conformal mapping to project
$$
\{z \in \Omega \mid \Im(z) > 0\}
$$
onto the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$. Can someone give me a first conformal map to a more practical region I can work with?
Thanks in advance.

Is does not matter what you choose for $a$ and $c$. If $f$ maps $\Omega$ onto a sector then so does any constant multiple of $f$.

Take a look at the (simulation) picture below where the red points belong to $\Omega$ and the green points are their images by Möbius transform :
$$f(z)=-\frac{z+1}{z-1}$$
which is indeed angular sector
$$|\arg(f(z))|< \theta \ \text{with} \ \theta=3 \pi/4.$$
Remarks :

The complementary set of the angular sector is an angular sector with a $\pi/2$ opening, which isn't surprizing because the boundary of $\Omega$ has already (two) $\pi/2$ angles that must be conformally mapped onto a (single) $\pi/2$ angle.

I have found $f$ by sending points $-1,0,1$ to $0,1,\infty$ resp.



Matlab program :
 a=3;
 f=@(z)(-(z+1)/(z-1))
 for k=1:5000
    r=sqrt(2)*sqrt(rand);
    t=2*pi*rand;
    s=sign(rand-0.5);
    z=s*i+r*exp(i*t);
    tz(k)=z;
    tZ(k)=f(z);
 end;
 plot(tz,'.r');axis([-a,a,-a,a]);axis equal;hold on;
 plot(tZ,'.g');axis equal;axis([-a,a,-a,a]);


See here and here as well.

Thank you very much for your answer. I am also curious how one can make such a simulation. It would come in handy for further exercises

@RIP I will write insert the (Matlab) program I have written.
